# how to add text on each rectangle in collection using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I am using matplotlib for plotting and convenient visualization of some graphs in xy coordinates.

I need to highlight some regions - and I use rectangles for this.

But I am interested to add some text upon each rectangle - to be able to distinguish those regions. How to do it using patches because I have a lot of objects in a plot?

Here is the code I use to plot rectangles:

```
# sample data for rectangles visualization
windows_df = pd.DataFrame( {'window_index_num': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}, 'left_pulse_num': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}, 'right_pulse_num': {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 6, 5: 7, 6: 8, 7: 9, 8: 10, 9: 11}, 'idx_of_left_pulse': {0: 0, 1: 4036, 2: 4080, 3: 4107, 4: 4368, 5: 4491, 6: 4529, 7: 4624, 8: 4626, 9: 4639}, 'idx_of_right_pulse': {0: 4080, 1: 4107, 2: 4368, 3: 4491, 4: 4529, 5: 4624, 6: 4626, 7: 4639, 8: 4679, 9: 4781}, 'left_pulse_pos_in_E': {0: 10.002042118364418, 1: 40.29395464818188, 2: 41.19356816747343, 3: 41.76060061888303, 4: 47.90221207147802, 5: 51.27679395217831, 6: 52.39165780468267, 7: 55.37561818764979, 8: 55.47294132608167, 9: 55.99635666692289}, 'right_pulse_pos_in_E': {0: 41.19356816747343, 1: 41.76060061888303, 2: 47.90221207147802, 3: 51.27679395217831, 4: 52.39165780468267, 5: 55.37561818764979, 6: 55.47294132608167, 7: 55.99635666692289, 8: 57.33777021469516, 9: 60.984834434908144}, 'idx_window_left_border': {0: 0, 1: 3990, 2: 4058, 3: 4093, 4: 4237, 5: 4429, 6: 4510, 7: 4576, 8: 4625, 9: 4632}, 'idx_window_right_border': {0: 4094, 1: 4238, 2: 4430, 3: 4510, 4: 4577, 5: 4625, 6: 4633, 7: 4659, 8: 4730, 9: 4792}, 'left_win_pos_in_E': {0: 10.002042118364418, 1: 39.38459790393702, 2: 40.74003692229216, 3: 41.46513255508269, 4: 44.66179219947279, 5: 49.53272998148, 6: 51.82972979173252, 7: 53.82159300113625, 8: 55.40803086073492, 9: 55.76645477820397}, 'right_win_pos_in_E': {0: 41.48613320837913, 1: 44.6852679849016, 2: 49.56014983071213, 3: 51.82972979173252, 4: 53.85265044341121, 5: 55.40803086073492, 6: 55.79921126600202, 7: 56.66110947958804, 8: 59.119140585251095, 9: 61.39880967219205}, 'window_width': {0: 4095, 1: 249, 2: 373, 3: 418, 4: 341, 5: 197, 6: 124, 7: 84, 8: 106, 9: 161}, 'window_width_in_E': {0: 31.48409109001471, 1: 5.300670080964579, 2: 8.820112908419965, 3: 10.364597236649828, 4: 9.190858243938415, 5: 5.875300879254915, 6: 3.9694814742695, 7: 2.8395164784517917, 8: 3.7111097245161773, 9: 5.632354893988079}, 'sum_pulses_duration_in_E': {0: 0.5157099691135514, 1: 0.5408987779694527, 2: 0.6869248977656355, 3: 0.7304908951030242, 4: 0.7269657511683718, 5: 0.537271616198268, 6: 0.7609034761658222, 7: 0.6178183490930067, 8: 0.8269277926972265, 9: 0.5591109437337494}, 'sum_pulse_sq': {0: 3.7944375922206044, 1: 3.8756992116858715, 2: 2.9661915477796663, 3: 3.070559830941317, 4: 3.0597037730539385, 5: 10.2020204659669, 6: 45.77535573608872, 7: 45.87630607524008, 8: 39.10335270063814, 9: 3.437205923490125}, 'pulse_to_window_rate': {0: 0.01638001769335214, 1: 0.10204347180781788, 2: 0.07788164447530765, 3: 0.0704794290047244, 4: 0.0790966122938326, 5: 0.09144580460471718, 6: 0.1916883807363909, 7: 0.2175787158769594, 8: 0.22282493757444324, 9: 0.09926770493999569}, 'max_height_in_window': {0: 20.815950580921104, 1: 20.815950580921104, 2: 5.324888970962656, 3: 5.324888970962656, 4: 5.14075603114903, 5: 86.81228155905252, 6: 110.06755904473022, 7: 110.06755904473022, 8: 110.06755904473022, 9: 14.735092268739246}, 'min_height_in_window': {0: -0.011928180619527797, 1: 1.6172637244080776, 2: 1.6172637244080776, 3: 0.8658702248969847, 4: 0.8658702248969847, 5: 0.8658702248969847, 6: 1.8476229914953515, 7: 2.918666252051556, 8: 3.2397786967451707, 9: 2.4893555139463266}, 'windows_sq': {0: 655.3712842149647, 1: 110.33848645112575, 2: 46.96612194869083, 3: 55.19032951390669, 4: 47.24795994896218, 5: 510.0482741740266, 6: 436.911136546121, 7: 312.538647650477, 8: 408.4727887246568, 9: 82.9932690531994}} )

fig_w, axs_w = plt.subplots()

#theoretical cross-section
#axs_w.plot(df_wo_NANS['E'], df_wo_NANS['theo_cs'], marker = "o", markersize = 1, linewidth = 1.0, alpha=0.6, color = 'green', label = 'Theo Cross Section')
axs_w.grid(color = 'grey', linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.2)

#windows rectangular
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
boxes = []

for index,row in windows_df.iterrows():
    current_rect_left_corner = (row['left_win_pos_in_E'], row['min_height_in_window'])
    current_w = row['window_width_in_E']
    current_h = row['max_height_in_window']-row['min_height_in_window']

    boxes.append(Rectangle(current_rect_left_corner, current_w, current_h))

    left = row['left_win_pos_in_E']
    right = row['right_win_pos_in_E']
    bottom = row['min_height_in_window']
    top = row['max_height_in_window']

    #mark of the start of the current window
    axs_w.text(
        left, #left corner,  #0.5*(left+right), #middle of the rectangle
        top, #top
        str(index),
        horizontalalignment='center',
        verticalalignment='center',
        fontsize=5
        )
        
    #mark of the end of the current window
    axs_w.text(
        right, #right corner,  #0.5*(left+right), #middle of the rectangle
        top+0.5*bottom, #top
        str(index)+'e',
        horizontalalignment='center',
        verticalalignment='center',
        fontsize=5
        )

pc = PatchCollection(boxes, facecolor='y', alpha=0.2, edgecolor='black')
axs_w.add_collection(pc)
```

Added text marks using cycle but is it possible to do it using patch and collections to make more efficient code?

Comment: You could use something like `axs_w.text(current_rect_left_corner[0]+current_w/2, current_rect_left_corner[1]+current_h/2, text, ha='center', va='center')`, for   all the texts you want to add.  Your post would be easier to understand with reproducible test data, or at least an image of the current output.

Comment: I have edited the code for better understanding and used the approach you recommend. But it seems it's inefficient because I have about 10k rectangles and text looks not very good especially when I have various rectangles heights.. I don't know how to make it more native and visualize the number of window user is seeing at the current moment. It's perfect if the number of current window will popup when mouse is over that region but it seems it's impossible to do it in matplotlib..